# What's the problem of this one-hot encoding?

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
In [4]: data = pd.read_csv('student_data.csv')

In [5]: data[:10]
Out[5]: 
   admit  gre   gpa  rank
0      0  380  3.61     3
1      1  660  3.67     3
2      1  800  4.00     1
3      1  640  3.19     4
4      0  520  2.93     4
5      1  760  3.00     2
6      1  560  2.98     1
7      0  400  3.08     2
8      1  540  3.39     3
9      0  700  3.92     2

one_hot_data = pd.get_dummies(data['rank'])

# TODO: Drop the previous rank column
data = data.drop('rank', axis=1)
data = data.join(one_hot_data)
# Print the first 10 rows of our data
data[:10]
```

It always gives an error:

```
KeyError: 'rank'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6a749c8f286e> in <module>()
      1 # TODO:  Make dummy variables for rank
----> 2 one_hot_data = pd.get_dummies(data['rank'])
      3 
      4 # TODO: Drop the previous rank column
      5 data = data.drop('rank', axis=1)
```

Comment: What is `print (data.columns.tolist())` ? Maybe some encoding or whitespace traling problem.

Comment: In [13]: print (data.columns.tolist()) ['admit', 'gre', 'gpa', 1, 2, 3, 4].

Comment: Strange. it's good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If get:

> KeyError: 'rank'

it means there is no column `rank`. Obviously problem is with traling whitespace or encoding.

```
print (data.columns.tolist())
['admit', 'gre', 'gpa', 'rank']
```

Your solution should be simplify by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) - it select column and remove from original `DataFrame`:

```
data = data.join(pd.get_dummies(data.pop('rank')))
# Print the first 10 rows of our data
print(data[:10])
   admit  gre   gpa  1  2  3  4
0      0  380  3.61  0  0  1  0
1      1  660  3.67  0  0  1  0
2      1  800  4.00  1  0  0  0
3      1  640  3.19  0  0  0  1
4      0  520  2.93  0  0  0  1
5      1  760  3.00  0  1  0  0
6      1  560  2.98  1  0  0  0
7      0  400  3.08  0  1  0  0
8      1  540  3.39  0  0  1  0
9      0  700  3.92  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine. You can need to rerun the previous cells which includes loading of the data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).